# Should I ask if I'm going to be terminated?

Tags: resignation

I'm a new hire, around 3 months into this new software company, sadly right after the COVID strikes, I have been a full remote worker since going to the office is not an option.

So I have very minimal connection to people in the company to ask or discuss about this.

From the daily meetings and status updates, it seems that probably there's little to almost no project since the client is cutting costs and reducing requests to our company.

It is still not a fixed situation, but since I'm the newest hire probably I'm gonna be cut first than all the other seniors, since I think that would be the wise action (minimal people with max experience and knowledge of the system).

My question is, is it okay to ask my manager about the situation and the future of the job, so if I'm going to be terminated, I can have a head start looking for new job.

Also, I'm an outsource employee, I have asked about my contract with the headhunter agent I'm in but their response was not good, like if the company decided to let me go, the headhunter will just terminate the contract right away.

Comment: Assume the best, prepare for the worst.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> I'm the newest hire probably I'm gonna be cut first than all the other seniors, since I think that would be the wise action (minimal people with max experience and knowledge of the system).

This is not a good assumption. [Many companies do not meaningfully value experience.](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/157924/why-the-disparity-between-raises-within-a-company-and-raises-when-changing-compa/157932#157932)  Instead, they chop by salary, which means they let go all the more senior people who have higher salaries.

I live in Calgary, where there have been a lot of layoffs and furloughs. A lot of the junior people are surviving because they are cheap.

> My question is, is it okay to ask my manager about the situation and the future of the job, so if I'm going to be terminated, I can have a head start looking for new job.

You cannot trust the answer anyway, so you could ask, but because you cannot make decisions based on the answer,  you should start looking for a new job anyway.

> Also, I'm an outsource employee, I have asked about my contract with the headhunter agent I'm in but their response was not good, like if the company decided to let me go, the headhunter will just terminate the contract right away.

This is the far more relevant thing to whether you will be laid off first. Contractors are usually the first people eliminated, no matter their seniority.

Comment: Last paragraph is the most important, it's one of the dangers of being a contractor

Comment: And also why, as a contractor, you are always on the hunt for the next gig. Employees should be doing it too, to some degree, but with contractors its crucial.

Comment: "You cannot trust the answer anyway."  This says it all I know that wehn we had our first layoffs they came out and said that they cut even more than the should have and said dont worry and then the next round hit\

Answer (score 3):

> My question is, is it okay to ask my manager about the situation and the future of the job, so if I'm going to be terminated, I can have a head start looking for new job.

Yes you should ask but don't expect to get a real answer. During redundancy times very few companies will give out any info about this as it will cause rumours which will cause people to leave prematurely. The company want's the choice of who says and who goes which comes to the next point.

> Also, I'm an outsource employee

You're first to go. If I were you I'd start looking around for another job now don't ask anyone and don't wait if you see something. Start doing applications / interviews as much as humanly possible.

> like if the company decided to let me go, the headhunter will just terminate the contract right away.

This is usually how it works with contractors and is the main reason companies use them as they can be got rid of more easily that full time employees.

Comment: Just as Dave implies, it's largely pointless since, you quite simply will get a meaningless answer.